# bash script to back up file

Tags: bash, cron, log

I have a few files to be backed up. I need a script to check line number of a file and if it exceeds, say 8000 lines, it will simply zip it and name it with date prefix format.
I need your help.

Comment: What about using a version control system instead?

Comment: @choroba
what do you mean with `control system`? I have no info about it.

Comment: Check [Revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). Check SVN, Git, and so on.

Comment: @choroba
yes, the terminology fits in my case. I believe there are powerful tools to manage it. I ll take a look at it in detail.

Comment: Is this a log file? Did you look into [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This script will get the line numbers, then if it is more than 7999 (greater than or equal to 8000) it will make a .tar.gz of the file.

```
#! /bin/bash

lif=$(wc -l < /home/USER/path/to/file.txt)

if [ "$lif" -gt 7999 ]; then
    tar /home/USER/path/to/where/you/want/the/backup/to/be/filename-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M).tar.gz /home/USER/path/to/file.txt
```

Don't for get to chmod the script to get it to run - `chmod +x /home/USER/path/to/script.sh`

The cron command would be `0    17  *   *   *   /home/USER/path/to/script.sh` to run every dday at 5pm. Use [this generator](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/jslibrary/demos/crontab.php) to help get the cron command if you want it to be different.

Thanks [@Jnuk](https://askubuntu.com/users/309420/jnuk) for the generator!

Comment: To execute it automatically, you can set up a cronjob. You can f.e. use [this generator](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/jslibrary/demos/crontab.php)

Comment: @Tim
For sure :) You deserved that

Comment: @Tim don't parse the output of `cat` command. Just `wc -l < file` would be enough.

Comment: Why are you `tar`ing a single file?

Comment: @Dan I had a file once that was 0.5 GB, it's sensible to zip things up sometimes.

Comment: My point is that you could use `gzip` directly. (Note that by default it'll replace the file -- read the `man` page!)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample script that does what you describe

```
#!/bin/sh

FILENAME=$1
LINES=$(cat "$FILENAME" |wc  | awk '{print $1}')
MAXLINE="8000"
DATE=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')
BACKUP_PATH="/path/to/files/"


do_backup(){
        tar xvf ""backup_$DATE.tar"" "$BACKUP_PATH"
}

if [ "$LINES" -gt "$MAXLINE" ];
then
        do_backup
fi
```

First it declares som variables,

FILENAME is the file you want to check the length of.

LINES  iis the amount of lines we find i the file we check

MAXLINES is the max amount of lines we allow before making a backup.

DATE is todays date in Year-Month-Day format

BACKUP_PATH is the directory you are going to backup.

do_backup  is the function that contains backup command

save the script into a file
in terminal:

```
chmod +x  script_name
```

to make it executable

./script_name /path/to/file_to_check_rows_of

If you want to understand more of how the script works try running it with:

sh -x script_name